# Remove whitespace above header

Tags: removing-whitespace

So I'm designing the website for my dad's company and I'm trying to get rid of the whitespace above the header on the page. I tried making the margins 0 and paddings 0 but nothing is changing. Here is my code and a [link to the website](http://www.hv-eng.com/index):

```
header {
font-size: 20px;
position: relative;
background-color: #DDDDDD;
height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the the w3-sidebar-class you are using inside the page. It sets the top margin to a negative value. In order to analys these kind of problems, I suggest you start from a black html page and add new elements to it step by step. Then you can see which changes have which effect.